# Visual studio 2013 preview SPA template

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm unable to get the SPA template to work from Visual Studio 2013.

I've installed the Web Tools update, and created a fresh project choosing the Web SPA template option.

unfortunately, I get the error

> An unknown error occurred.

This is caused by a failed webapi request which has the following error message (from fiddler):

> No OWIN environment is available for the request

I can't find any information anywhere on how to get this to run.. can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a VB based project or C#? Would it be possible for you to share a repro project?

Comment: This is a C# based project

Comment: Could you share the repro project as it would help in diagnosing the problem?

Comment: You probably won't need a repro project given the the info in my answer but let me know if you do

Comment: Thanks Martin. Actually your information was helpful in finding out the issue. Our team has looked into it and it seems this is a known issue which has already been fixed and would be available by next release (RC). We are planning to put this information into 'known issues' list of current release notes too. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

Don't use a space in the project name

---

Kiran, I went to reproduce the problem from scratch. I messed around with the first project (trying to get it to work) so much that I didn't think it would be much help in diagnosing the problem.

The new project worked fine... Isn't it great when you can't reproduce the problem?

Well I looked carefully at what I did differently.. couldn't think of anything, yet yesterday, I spent all evening trying to get this work... I'd recreated the project from scratch several times!

Finally I realised... I named my project "Test SPA" whereas today I was too lazy to write such a long name.. just called it "SPA".

Just created a new project with a space in the name.. and have successfully reproduced the problem.

Let me know if you still need me to send a project, I think you should be able to repro without one though if you use a space in the project name